# When did Internet Explorer introduce readyState property on the document object?

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer, dom, readystate

Internet Explorer supports the readyState property on the document...

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ie/ms534359(v=vs.85).aspx

But which version of IE was this introduced in?

Comment: It was introduced in December 1997 update IE4.01. Not supported by other UA's up to DOM Core Level 3. Even though it was proposed to W3C one year ahead and it was part of the working draft...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

it was introduced in IE4:
[see here](http://javascript.gakaa.com/script-readystate.aspx)